# Spinner dropdown height to match parent

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is it possible to adjust height of `Spinner` dropdown to fill the entire screen. Right now i have 3 items that i dynamically add into the spinner adapter but these only cover half of the screen. What i have right now is something like this:

[image]

What i want is something like this:

[image]

I could add empty items but that won't solve the problem for different screen sizes

I tried to implement a style on the spinner but it didn't work

```
<style name="MyCustomSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown">
    <item name="android:dropDownHeight">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

I have a view between action bar and spinner so i cannot use `layout_weight=1` for my spinner

Comment: it means you doesnt  scroll it?

Comment: have you tried custom spinner??

Comment: I think you should go with, Button in place of Spinner, and Use Custom AlertDialog with Layout fill parent to Show your Spinner Items.. i think it may help You.

Answer (score 1):

try using this with your adapter.

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is by writing your own view that works like a spinner.

Answer (score -1):

In yourspinner.xml,
add the `android:minHeight="48dp"` to TextView element. see the example below-

```
<TextView 

     android:id="@+id/textViewRowFacility"
     android:minHeight="50dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your Spinner in LinearLayout & set spinner weight to 1 like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the weight of the spinner to take the entire space. If no other view is there in the Layout then use this code:

```
<Spinner

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

To learn more about android weight refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean):

[What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

Comment: yeah but i have other views in my layout

Comment: and i want the dropdown box to only fit the whole screen and not the entire spinner itself

Answer (score -1):

Try using the code below

```
ArrayAdapter<String> yourSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, yourItem) {

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                parent);

        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = convertView.getLayoutParams();
        p.height = 100; // assign the required height here
        convertView.setLayoutParams(p);

        return convertView;
    }
};
```